# Is the location.hash/anchor part of the URL forwarded by the browser and is it safe to rely on this?

Tags: php, url-routing, forward

I was wondering, if it is safe to forward the location hash part of an URL. As the hash/anchor part (#something) is not readable with PHP, it can't be redirected as a part of URL.

However, it seems that the browser will do this job. Say you append #test to any bit.ly URL, the browser will forward #test to the target URL.

I could reproduce this behavior in different browsers like Chrome and IE. And therefore I'm asking:

**Is it safe to rely on the browser, forwarding the hash/anchor part of the URL?**

Use case: AddThis tracking combined with bit.ly short links, but I don't want to give Addthis my bit.ly API creds.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "forwarding"?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean (PHP) header redirects like: "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently, Location: http://www.example.com/something/"

Comment: So you're asking whether `header('Location: http://example.com/#fragment')` will work?

Comment: Well, no. Say you go to example.com/test.php#fragment, the php code looks like this: `header('Location: http://example.com/test2.php')` the browser will still redirect you to example.com/test2.php#fragment. (Already working, tested in IE, Firefox, Chrome) - but I want to know if it is safe, to rely on the browser to "forward" the #fragment (is this a browser specification or just something only some browsers do)?